# Azure AD share Managed Service Identities across tenants/subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure AD have B2B collaboration for inviting external users.

But what if i wan't to invite an external Azure service that have a MSI.

Is it possible to create an Azure AD group and add a external(another subscription/tenant in Azure) MSI which i can then use to grant access to resources?

Say I wan't to allow a B2B partners Data Factory access to SQL database of ours and I do not wan't to give them a SQL Login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSIs are service principals which cannot be invited to other tenants. They are always tenant-specific.

The scenario sounds like you need to give access to something connected to your tenant.
I would suggest creating an App registration (Application),
adding a key, and giving those credentials to the other service.
You can then give the application access to your Azure subscription etc.

Comment: The point is it is not connected to my tenant. But oh well. And i wan't to avoid username and password.